# Redirecionar com .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Alguém saberia me auxiliar na alteração de uma URL amigável.

Exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nome-da-nova-url-([A-Za-z-]+)\.htm$ url.php?url=$1
```

Gostaria que tudo que estiver em *www.meusite.com/nomedaurl.htm* fosse para *www.meusite.com/nome-da-nova-url-nomedaurl.htm*.

Se existe a possibilidade de redirecionar:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)\.htm$ url.php?url=$1
```

Para:

```
RewriteRule ^nome-da-nova-url-([A-Za-z-]+)\.htm$ url.php?url=$1
```

Comment: não entendi.. a regra atual já não está fazendo isso?